# DateTime variable set to empty

Tags: c#

I would like to set null to DateTime variable:

```
DateTime SaleDate = null;
```

Got error:

```
Cannot convert null to 'System.Data.Time' because it is a non-nullable value type.
```

Why I can't set to null?
What is best way to tell system `DateTime` variable is not set to any value?

Comment: `DateTime? SaleDate = null` or `DateTime SaleDate = DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime is a value-type so you need to use `Nullable<DateTime>` (or ? syntactic sugar `DateTime?` ) to set null value.

```
DateTime? SaleDate = null;
```